# glXMakeCurrent never returns in multiple multithreaded linux opengl applications

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, xlib, juce

I am running 3 instances of a JUCE-based multithreaded OpenGL application on one machine - each of the instances is connected to a separate X display. The main application thread calls `XInitThreads` followed by `XOpenDisplay` to the appropriate display. A different thread is then used for the main rendering loop. The 3 instances of the application are initialized after each other, so that one is finished with the graphics setup when the next is starting up.

In 80% of the cases everything starts up fine, but sometimes in the second and/or third instance of the application the 4th call to `glXMakeCurrent` (which is also the 1st one made from a different thread than the one on which the connection was initialized) never returns. X threads have been initialized, the threads are using locks, and right before the call to `glXMakeCurrent` the X Display is locked via `XLockDisplay` (and unlocked after the call returns).

I made sure that each application uses the correct display & context. If it was purely related to problem of multiple threads accessing the same display connection then it should be equally likely that the first instance encounters this problem - but it never does.

Any ideas why `glXMakeCurrent` may not return, even though it has exclusive access to its X display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I was wrong, the problem appears to have been caused by a missing lock on the JUCE OpenGL context. Hence, the X display lock was acquired correctly, but the context to which it was supposed to be mapped was (in the problem cases) being accessed concurrently by the other thread, causing `glXMakeCurrent` to deadlock.